# Why should you implement IDisposable to clean up unmanaged resources only?

Tags: c#, .net

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.1#implementing-idisposable) says

> You should implement IDisposable only if your type uses unmanaged resources directly.

Coming from a mostly Java background, this sounds strange to me. Suppose I have a class that contains an IDisposable member:

```
class Foo : IDisposable {
    private StreamWriter sw;
    ...
}
```

... and suppose this class is used, for example, as a sort of filter that takes strings and modifies them and then outputs them with the StreamWriter `sw`. I want to use this class like a sort of Writer.

Why wouldn't I want to implement `Dispose(bool)` which would call `sr.Dispose()?` This is what I would have to do if I were coding it in Java (the Java `Closable` interface is similar to .NET's `IDisposable`, though in some ways different). Yet the documentation says I shouldn't, because I'm not directly using unmanaged resources.

If I don't override `Dispose(bool)`, how does the managed resource `sw` get disposed when I leave the block started by the `using` statement?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier the garbage collector only cleans managed resources. It have no knowledge of unmanaged resources. That's why we have the `IDisposable` interface to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement `IDisposable` when your class contains an `IDisposable` field such as for example a `StreamWriter`.

In this case you can assume that your type does use unmanaged resources (through the `StreamWriter` class) under the hood, and you should always dispose any object that implements the `IDisposable` interface as soon as you are done using them.

> Why wouldn't I want to implement `IDisposable(bool)` which would call `sr.Dispose()`?

You certainly would.

> If I don't override `Dispose(bool)`, how does the managed resource `sw` get disposed when I leave the block started by the `using` statement?

It doesn't. The underlying unmanaged resource(s) may eventually be released by the finalizer (depending on the implementation of the `IDisposable` class) but the managed object won't be disposed unless you explicitly dispose it in your class.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, too. So why does Microsoft say "You should implement IDisposable only if your type uses unmanaged resources **directly**" rather than saying you ought to implement it even if it uses resources "under the hood"?

Comment: I can't answer that because I didn't wrote the docs :) But I guess they mean that you do use unmanaged resources "directly" *through* the IDisposable instance. If you look here it says that you should "implement the Basic Dispose Pattern on types containing instances of disposable types": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern.

Comment: @mm8 Sorry, but that's nonsense. That's redefining "directly" to mean "indirectly". The correct response is that the MS documentation is simply flat out wrong here. :)

Comment: @hvd: I don't argue with you on that one :)

Comment: You are misreading the documentation, and confusing Dispose(bool) with Dispose(). Dispose(bool) is a suggested pattern when implementing a finalizer. Dispose() is the method defined on IDisposable.

Answer (score 3):

When you use an instance that implements the `IDisposable` interface, it's best practice to use it as a local variable inside a `using` statement.
However, that's not always possible.
In some cases you must include a field that implements the `IDisposable` interface. In these cases, you should also implement it yourself and dispose them in your class `Dispose(bool)` method.

For instance, Suppose you want to schedule a task. One fairly easy implementation is to use a class that contains a `System.Timers.Timer` field, a start, stop, and doWork method.
In such a case you can't use the timer as a local variable, it must be a field, and therefor your class should implement the `IDisposable` interface and dispose the timer on it's `Dispose(bool)` method.

Here is a simplified code example (a bit too simplified, I guess, but good enough for this demonstration)

```
public abstract class Schedualer : IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public Schedualer(double interval)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(interval);
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_timer != null)
            {
                _timer.Elapsed -= _timer_Elapsed;
                _timer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnTimerElapsed();

    protected void StartTimer()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        try
        {
            TimerElapsed();
        }
        finally 
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moradof Improved it to prevent a "Zombie" state where the application keeps running but timer has stopped.

Comment: `IDisposible`  provides method `Dispose` that i understand, but i don't understand where from method `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` comes, is it required for every `IDispose` implementation?

Comment: @sairfan You can read all about it in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern)